# Use a pickled custom-class in another file without importing the class first

Tags: python, pickle

Say I have file `creator.py` with the following code

```py
class Mapper:
    def train(self, X,y):
         return self
    def predict(self, X):
        pass
```

I want to distribute this object, e.g in a google-cloud storage, such that my co-workes have access to that class aswell.

I thought it would be as easy as just using pickle to save a `Mapper` instance e.g

```py
import pickle


mapper = Mapper()
mapper.train(X,y)

with open("my_mapper.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(f,mapper)
```

and then in another script, in another repo, `main.py` I can un-pickle it

```py
import pickle
download_model_from_storage("my_mapper.pkl") # Download the object from storage
with open("my_mapper.pkl","rb") as f:
    my_mapper = pickle.load(f)
```

but that throws the error

`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Mapper' on <module '__main__' from 'c:\\code\\main.py'>`.

The only way I can fix this is to first import `Mapper` in `main.py`, but that introduces a file that I'll need to track in case I want to do some changes in `creator.py` then I should make sure those changes are also in `main.py` (which is rather prone to errors).

Isn't there a way to just distribute custom classes without having access to the "mother-class"? And why not (if that's the case)